# How to represent a Neither/ Nor set operation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Given:

> ***A*** = ***{ Aaron's friends }***
>
> ***B*** = ***{Bob's friends}***
>
> ***X*** = ***{all members in network}***

Set of friends in the network that are friends of **neither** Aaron **nor** Bob

I got as answer:

> $X-(A \cup B)$

Is this operation correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Yes; "neither ... nor" is, in boolean reasoning, $\lnot p \land \lnot q$ i.e., by DeMorgan : $\lnot (p \lor q)$. Thus, in set algebra, must be the *complement* of the *union* : $(A \cup B)^c$.

Comment: $(X-A)\cap(X-B)$ also works. (It turns out that they're the same set; we have $X-(A\cup B)=(X-A)\cap(X-B)$. If something's in one, then it's in the other.)

Comment: it depends on whether you want to doubly exclude friends of both Aaron and Bob

Answer (score 2):

The "Set of friends in the network that are friends of neither Aaron nor Bob"
is
The "Set of elements in $X$ that are not in $A$ and are not in $B$"

$$=\{x\in X\mid (x\notin A) \land (x\notin B)\}=\{x\in X\mid (x\in A^c) \land (x\in B^c)\}=$$ $$\{x\in X\mid (x\in A^c\cap B^c)\}=\{x\in X\mid (x\in (A \cup B)^c\}=X-(A \cup B)$$